# Trouble understanding how $|e^z|=e^{Re(z)}=e^x$ but not $e^x(cos(y))$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Im not sure how $e^{Re(z)}=e^x$ and $e^x(cos(y))$ are equivalent given $z = x+iy$

Comment: The first one is the magnitude, the second one is the real part.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja but $e^{Re(z)}= e^x$ not $e^xcos(y)$

Comment: Which is why they are not equivalent

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja  true,sorry, thanks.

Comment: $|e^{i Im(z)}|=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different numbers

$$\mbox{Re} (e^z) = \mbox{Re} (e^{x+iy} )=\mbox{Re} (e^x\cos y + ie^x\sin y )=e^x \cos y$$
$$|e^z |=\sqrt{(e^x\cos y)^2 + (e^x\sin y)^2}=e^x\sqrt{\cos^ y + sin^2 y} =e^x =e^{\mbox{Re} z}$$